# How to force the value on init?

Tags: python

I have defined following class of a bank account. The account should always start with 0.0 balance. How can I enforce that the value is always set 0.0 even if the user set it differently at the initiation?

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self, name, balance=0.0):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
    def add_money(self, deposit_amnt):
        self.balance += deposit_amnt
    def withdraw_money(self, withdraw_amnt):
        if withdraw_amnt > self.balance:
            raise ValueError('Withdraw amount is more than balance')
        else:
            self.balance -= withdraw_amnt
    def check_balance(self):
        return self.balance

my_account = Account('Tim', 15)
my_account.check_balance()
>>> 15
```

Comment: ?????? `self.balance = 0`?

Comment: Just remove the balance parameter from `__init__` and set it to zero instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ommit balance in `__init__` if you want to start with 0. You have add method to do that later.

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.balance = 0
```